# How to upload my file and photo and add to databases

Tags: php

I want to upload a picture.
I wrote a codes for this ... but this photo is not added to the database at all. And Just, "**else**"  is executed.

```
public function store(Request $request){
    //Get Request Input
    $name        = $request ->input('name');
    $description = $request ->input('description');
    $cover_image = $request ->file('cover_image');
    $owner_id    = 1;
    //Check Image Upload
    if($cover_image)
    {

    $cover_image_filename = $cover_image -> getClientOriginalName();
    $cover_image -> move(public_path('images'), $cover_image_filename);
    }

else{
        $cover_image_filename = 'noimage.jpg';  
    }
    //Insert Gallery
DB::table('galleries')-> insert(
    [
        'name'              => $name,
        'description'       => $description,
        'cover_image'       => $cover_image_filename,
        'owner_id'          => $owner_id
    ]
);
    //Redirect
    return \Redirect::route('gallery.index') -> with('message', 'Gallery Created');
}`
```

what's the wrong?

Comment: `$request ->file('cover_image')` does return 0 or some falsy value. Go check the docs about this file function

Comment: or maybe you have a typo in your html part... provide a MCVE

Comment: yes.. I..know. but..I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form and a `<input type="file">` with field `name="cover_image"`

2) Create a new folder named `images` in your laravel `public` folder.

3) In your `controller`

```
public function store(Request $request){
    //Get Request Input
    $name = $request ->input('name');
    $description = $request ->input('description');
    $owner_id  = 1;

    //Check Image Upload
    if( $request->hasFile('cover_image')) {

        $cover_image = $request->file('cover_image');
        $path = public_path(). '/images/';

        $cover_image_filename = $cover_image->getClientOriginalName();
        $cover_image->move($path, $cover_image_filename);
    }

    else{

        $cover_image_filename = 'noimage.jpg';
    }

    //Insert Gallery
    DB::table('galleries')-> insert([
        'name'              => $name,
        'description'       => $description,
        'cover_image'       => $cover_image_filename,
        'owner_id'          => $owner_id
    ]);

    //Redirect
    return \Redirect::route('gallery.index') -> with('message', 'Gallery Created');

}
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Yes
I've done these things before.
 I've done this code you changed now.
 But the result did not change.

Comment: What result not changed?

Comment: The image will not be added to the database and only the "else" is executed and "noimage" will be added to the database

Comment: Post your form and route too.

Comment: Ok..Thanks..a lot.
Good luck.